# Does Tomcat 7.x require me to set any environment variables?

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I am currently reading `Head First: Servlet and JSP`. They want me to use Tomcat 5.5 (which is almost outdated). Instead I downloaded `Tomcat 7.x`.

Now, I was following their instructions on writing the first servlet but I think I will have to set some paths. I have set the `path` for `jdk`'s bin directory so I can compile Java programs from command line, if I want to.

**Does Tomcat require me to set any environment variables ?

If so, which? And how ?**

Path to my Tomcat home looks like this: `D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35`

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Comment: @Rob Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need JAVA_HOME to be set. Look in catalina.bat.

Comment: and to what value should I set JAVA_HOME ? OK I found `catalina.sh` in bin folder. What next ?

Comment: It has to point to where java is installed, wherever the JDK is installed. (Assuming you installed that since you are a dev, you can use JRE_HOME if you use a JRE.)

Comment: Ok so `JAVA_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\Java` ? Sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: if that's the base of your java install is

Comment: It should be the `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09`, but I seem to recall reading that Java may have (had?) a problem with spaces in paths; also you should use `/`s instead of `\`s or double the `\\`s.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are on Windows, the file you need to look at is `catalina.bat`, not `catalina.sh` which is specific to Unix and Unix-like systems. If you are on cygwin, ignore my advice here and go with catalina.sh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set classpaths to your servlet-api, jsp-api, el-api, commons-beanutils, then you need to set ant_home, set tomcat_home and catalina_home

For example:

**c:/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/run.bat:**

set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07

set PATH="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07";%PATH%

set CLASSPATH=.;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib\el-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.0-BETA

set ANT_HOME=c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27

set TOMCAT_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27

set CATALINA_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27

C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin\startup.bat

`Another` method is to install NetBeans IDE and it will do everything for you- you just click RUN to run your Project